# In Tableau, how to plot a map with circles sizes proportional to the number of records that contain that location?

Tags: database, data-visualization, tableau-desktop

I am using Tableau Desktop 2021.
I have data in csv format, and in each record (row) I have the "city" field.
My data is a collection of **events**, so each record is an event, and I have several events (records) that happened in the same city.
So far, I managed to import the data, and I have created a **map**, with circles that mark the cities where events happened.

Now I would like to have the **size** of the circles proportional to the number of events happened in that city.

I am new to the interface, please help me to apply the right "size" property to the map.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add a "New calculation" to the "Marks" section, where you insert the following code (calculation):

```
COUNT([City])
```

Then, you need to drag-and-drop this new calculation item on top of the "Size" box, in the "Marks" box.
This will get the required result.

Note: up until the 2020 version of Tableau, the custom calculation code was different, it was SUM(Number of Records), and this can be found if you google for info on this task. However, since 2020 "Number of Records" is no more available, so the new "COUNT()" function needs to be used.

In the following, some screenshots showing the steps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]